# How do you type Mathjax faster?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

I am notorious for asking questions, but I would like to increase my answers rapport. I find it mainly that sometimes the questions on my level of math are taken up by higher math users who can type faster, is there a mathjax typing app to improve my skills?

Comment: Practice, practice, practice.

Comment: Indeed, practice!  I learned a whole lot of mathjax while earning my first 2000 rep.  I suggested edits, to practice.  They were usually accepted, but some accepted edits get further edited, by a reviewer.  So I'd click on those edits to see how I could improve.  (**Bonus**: until you reach 2000 in rep, any accepted suggested edit awards you 2 points.)  Even after reaching that rep mark, I would still edit, or review others edits, and good questions and answers, to learn things like formatting matrices, using the align environment... etc.